# Dell XPS 15 touchpad issues

Tags: dell, touchpad

I have a Dell XPS 15 9550, and I recently installed Ubuntu on it along with windows (separate drives). Ubuntu is great and I love it, but I ran into some troubles with my touchpad.

The XPS has a touchpad with no buttons, so the left and right click are just part of the trackpad. Ubuntu doesn't let me move the cursor when I have my finger on the left click area, like if I want to move the mouse and click something.

I did some searching and found some terminal code that I executed, that lets me move my mouse when the left click is held, but not when I just have my finger on it.

I know this is tricky, because I have the 2-finger scroll and such and I love it, but I was wondering if there was a way to fix this without messing up the gestures or anything.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? You can install libinput to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1710600) already submitted regarding a related issue.

If that bug affects you or related to you problem help raise its heat so it gets attention.